# Passing data from screen to screen not refreshing componentDidMount

Tags: react-router, react-redux, react-native

I am trying to load category from wordpress woocommerce api. I can able to pass category slug from navigator to category page. It renders the category products but the problem is need to navigate to other screen and come back to appropriate menu to see product changed. My code is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Platform,
    StatusBar,
    Image,
    TouchableHighlight, ToolbarAndroid,
    FlatList,
    ScrollView

} from "react-native";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import {Icon, Button, Container, Header, Content,Left ,Right,Item,Input,Card,CardItem} from 'native-base'
import { Ionicons,FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'

import FAIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper'
//import * as ProductAction from '../actions/ProductActions';



class Category extends Component {

    state={ 
        data:[],
    }

    fetchData = async() => {

        //response
        const namess = this.props.navigation.state.params.category; //This is product slug from navigator screen
        const response = await
        //Fetching cat using V1


        fetch("https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products?filter[product_cat]="+ namess +"&consumer_key=ck&consumer_secret=cs");
        //posts
        const posts = await response.json();
        this.setState({data:posts});
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        //page load
        this.fetchData();
        //this.props.ProductAction.getProducts();
    }
    static navigationOptions ={
        drawerIcon:(
                <FontAwesome name="home" size={30} color="black" />
            )
    }
    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        const namess = this.props.navigation.state.params.category; //This is product slug from navigator screen

        return (

            <Container>

            <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor:'#eeeeee'}}>
            <Card>
            <CardItem header style={{flex:1,height:50}}>
                <Text style={{paddingLeft:140,fontSize:18}}>
                    BLOUSE{namess}
                </Text>
            </CardItem>
            </Card>
            <View>
                    <FlatList contentContainerStyle={styles.list} numColumns={2} 
            data={this.state.data || []}
            keyExtractor = {(x,i) =>i.toString()}
            renderItem = {({item})=>
                <TouchableHighlight style={{width:'50%'}} onPress={() => navigate("Products", { product: item })} underlayColor="white">
                <View style={styles.view} >
          <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: item.images[0].src}} />
          <Text style={styles.text}>{item.name}</Text>
          <View style={styles.borderNow}></View>
          <View style={styles.cartPrice}>
              <Text style={styles.addCart}>₹{item.price}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.price}>

              </Text> 
              </View>
        </View>
                      </TouchableHighlight> 
            } />
            </View> 
                </ScrollView>
            </Container>

        )
    }
}
export default Category;
```

The `const namess` is the params i get from another screen I can able to render on pressing menu. But the variable namess in the `fetch(url)` is not refreshing but working. I need to render this current url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount()` will be fired when you see your category page for the first time, when navigating to another screen, the category page isn't **unmounted**, so `componentDidMount()` won't be called when you visit it again.

---

In order to get your data from the second screen, you can create a listener whenever the category page will be in focus, like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.navigation.addListener("willFocus", this.fetchData);
}
```